# How can I get the totals item count from Paypal Shopping Cart to my website?

Tags: php, paypal

I am using Paypal "**Add to Cart**" button in my website.

I want to show the total number of items added in cart.

How can I do this?

Thank you,

Comment: What you have tried so far, or do you really tried Google?

Comment: I have googled but only found the view cart button but not count of items of the cart.

Comment: as always, typical useless SO comments. I got here googling, just to find out I should "really try google" some more. Duh @PHP.  Anyway, does anyone have an example on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

When you add items to cart and load the cart to paypal than you get a token using the token you can get all the detail from your cart including no. of items in your cart.

Comment: thanks, how can I get the token? Can you send the documentation link or any thread related to this?

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/

Comment: These are two links of paypal documentation from where you can have some help about it